# Custom visualization in Cognos Analytics

Tags: javascript, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I look a guide about custom visualization in Cognos Analytics, because the IBM guide is completely unintelligible. I don't know how map a visualization code in Cognos. I know that I must run a "customvis create" procedure. The main problem is when i must edit the visualization code like:  https://observablehq.com/@d3/sankey-diagram , and define the variable in vizdef file.

Is anybody Who can explain this problem ?

Thanks,
Kamil